# How to get fields in Mysql from a couple of name/value fields

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have this data stored in the table in Mysql 5 database.

Table data

```
| attrName   | attrValue                |
-----------------------------------------
| price       | 12.23                   |
| current_p   | 23.99                   |
| price_dev   | 0.1222                  |
| timestamp   | 2009-07-14 00:00:00 EDT |
| price       | 14.23                   |
| current_p   | 13.11                   |
| price_dev   | 0.7444                  |
| timestamp   | 2009-07-14 00:01:00 EDT |
| price       | 11.00                   |
| current_p   | 18.55                   |
| price_dev   | 0.3572                  |
| timestamp   | 2009-07-14 00:02:00 EDT |
```

Now I want to do a query to display all data in this way (order by timestamp)

```
| timestamp               | price   | current_p | price_dev |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 2009-07-14 00:00:00 EDT | 12.23   | 23.99       | 0.1222  |
| 2009-07-14 00:01:00 EDT | 14.23   | 13.11       | 0.7444  |
| 2009-07-14 00:02:00 EDT | 11.00   | 18.55       | 0.3572  |
```

Could you suggest me the right query?

Thanks a lot,

pasquy73

Comment: Do a `select` statement where you parse the `attrValue` column using a `CASE` statement (to determine what column it will fall under) multiple times `as` your new column name

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909661/how-to-split-a-column-into-multiple-columns-ordered-by-date) is a very similar question

Comment: If this is a proper [EAV data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), there should be an Entity table somewhere that associates the attributes with each other. Otherwise, how do you know which attributes should be grouped into a single row of results?

Comment: @Abdul - there no way to do that. there is no key which attribute names from one product to group them

Comment: In the absence of an entity, this problem is essentially insoluble - as demonstrated by your sample output, which is obviously nonsensical.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I see...I did not look at the question fully before commenting

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be relying on the order of rows in the table to determine the "groups" of attributes.

But in SQL, there is no implicit order or position for rows in a table, you can only order or group rows by some value column.

So you must add a column to associate them:

```
| eventId | attrName   | attrValue                |
-------------------------------------------------
|    1234 | price       | 12.23                   |
|    1234 | current_p   | 23.99                   |
|    1234 | price_dev   | 0.1222                  |
|    1234 | timestamp   | 2009-07-14 00:00:00 EDT |
|    1235 | price       | 14.23                   |
|    1235 | current_p   | 13.11                   |
|    1235 | price_dev   | 0.7444                  |
|    1235 | timestamp   | 2009-07-14 00:01:00 EDT |
|    1236 | price       | 11.00                   |
|    1236 | current_p   | 18.55                   |
|    1236 | price_dev   | 0.3572                  |
|    1236 | timestamp   | 2009-07-14 00:02:00 EDT |
```

Then you can use various solutions, which are well-documented in other places under the [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) tag.

For example:

```
SELECT eventId,
  MAX(CASE attrName WHEN 'timestamp' THEN attrValue END) as timestamp,
  MAX(CASE attrName WHEN 'price' THEN attrValue END) as price,
  MAX(CASE attrName WHEN 'current_p' THEN attrValue END) as current_p,
  MAX(CASE attrName WHEN 'price_dev' THEN attrValue END) as price_dev,
FROM WhateverMyTableNameIs
GROUP BY eventid
```

If you don't want to do that, then you must store your data differently, putting attributes in proper columns instead of this key-value design.

Comment: Thank you all and Bill, I've solved the problem with the Bill's solution

Comment: Fortunately I've got a recTime parameter (as eventId).